# breaking a 32-bit number into individual fields

Tags: python

Is there a quick way in python to split a 32-bit variable, say, `a1a2a3a4` into `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4` quickly? I've done it by changing the value into hex and then splitting it, but it seems like a waste of time doing `int`->`string`->`int`.

Comment: Please explain what you think a Python "32-bit variable" is. If you are assuming that its value is unsigned, then say so. If not, please explain what you want the result to be.

Comment: i guess it is unsigned, since there is no reason for any of the values to be negative. 

i had meant a1,a2 to be like indexes in a large variable/string thing. i should have put x1x2x3x4, but this works just as well. im trying to write CAST128, and in part of it, temp bytes are stored in x1x2x3...x16, z1z2...z16. how would i operate on 4 at a time and update them?

Answer (score 15):

Standard library module [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) does short work of it:

```
>>> import struct
>>> x = 0xa1a2a3a4
>>> struct.unpack('4B', struct.pack('>I', x))
(161, 162, 163, 164)
```

"packing" with format `'>I'` makes `x` into a 4-byte string in big-endian order, which can then immediately be "unpacked" into four unsigned byte-size values with format `'4B'`.  Easy peasy.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for anyone looking at this now -- this doesn't work in Python 3.  TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: @ThatAintWorking Pardon? TypeError would only ever be raised here if you pass an integer into `struct.unpack()` (hence, yknow, the error text mentioning an int...), but if you notice, that won't ever happen with this answer because `struct.pack()` always returns a string... so it works 100% as expected, even on Python 3. I assume you forwent the nested pack and tried to pass an integer directly into `struct.unpack()` without noticing?

Comment: M. I. Wright, it's been too long. I don't even remember what I was working on when I got this, but you might be right that I was passing an int instead of a string.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't really such thing as a 32-bit variable in Python. Is this what you mean?

```
x = 0xa1a2a3a4
a4 = int(x & 0xff)
a3 = int((x >> 8) & 0xff)
a2 = int((x >> 16) & 0xff)
a1 = int(x >> 24)
```

As SilentGhost points out, you don't need the int conversion, so you can do this:

```
a4 = x & 0xff
a3 = (x >> 8) & 0xff
a2 = (x >> 16) & 0xff
a1 = x >> 24
```

Note that in older versions of Python, the second version will return longs if the value of x is greater than 0x7fffffff and ints otherwise. The first version always returns int. In newer versions of Python the two types are [unified](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) so you don't have to worry about this detail.

Comment: why are you doing `int` conversion?

Comment: SilentGhost: because he might be using Python 2.x and he might want the result as an int, not a long. It's not necessary, but it's not going to hurt either. You're welcome to omit the int conversion if you wish.

Comment: Silent Ghost: I have now posted both versions. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use bitwise operations.

For example:

```
myvar = 0xcdf100cd
a0 = myvar & 0xff
a1 = (myvar >> 8) & 0xff
a2 = (myvar >> 16) & 0xff
a3 = (myvar >> 24) & 0xff
```

the `&0xff` keeps the lower 8 bits of the value and zeros the rest, while the bitshift operator (`>>`) is used to shift the byte you extracting into these lower 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late but I usually do something like this:

```
hexnum = 0xa1a2a3a4
bytes = []
while (hexnum > 0):
    bytes.insert(0, hexnum & 0xff)
    hexnum >>= 8
```

Not sure though if it's more efficient then unpack or not (likely not due to use of list.insert()).